# Why does blocking cause a lock

Tags: clojure

I am using the following code for logging as a part of one handling of my request. This code has been seen many times everywhere. When I make multiple parallel calls, I get a deadlock because of this code.

```
(defn log [msg & vals]
  (let [line (apply format msg vals)]
    (locking System/out (println line))))
```

Anyone knows what could be going wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Summary

I'd conjecture that the deadlock is due to `log`'s interactions with other code; in particular, it is to be expected when testing at the REPL, for reasons which I demonstrate below. *(Meaning straight Clojure REPL, as opposed to `lein repl`, other nrepl-based repls etc.)*

The key issue involved has to do with synchronizing on `System/out`, which illustrates a broader point that **it is not a good idea to synchronize on objects provided by the JDK or Clojure themselves, as this may very well interfere with existing locking protocols involving those objects** (which is in fact the case with Clojure's `*out*` and `System/out`, as we'll see shortly). Another point this illustrates is that **locks do not compose**.

The answer begins by offering a solution and only then goes into details of the locking protocols involved in Clojure printing, as the latter discussion is a bit on the long side and the basic recommendation can be stated quite succinctly.

### Proposed solution

One way to look at this situation is that, as mentioned above, it doesn't tend to be a good idea to synchronize on objects which are provided by the core JVM classes or Clojure, as this may well interfere with locking protocols these objects are already part of. Instead, one can always introduce new sentinel objects which one then owns and synchronize on them:

```
(def ^:private log-sentinel (Object.))

(defn log [msg & vals]
  (let [line (apply format msg vals)]
    (locking log-sentinel
      (println line)))
```

You could still get interference from unrelated printouts in the form of output interleaving, but most of the time you simply shouldn't have any such printouts (except perhaps REPL prompt printouts, whose being out of order shouldn't be too much of a problem; debug printouts can use `log` as well, and anyway, those will be off in production, right?), and otherwise you may simply prefer to print logging output to a different output stream.

Additionally, for reasons to be discussed shortly, in this case it is not even necessary to use one's own lock, as long as one uses `print` in place of `println`; the fact that the `print` call only takes one argument here is key:

```
(defn log [msg & vals]
  (let [line (str (apply format msg vals) "\n")]
    (print line)))
```

You may add a call to `flush` at the end if you want to cause immediate printout. (It would then be possible for the `flush` to happen after another thread's `print`, but in any case the printouts will happen promptly.)

This version of `log` is the one I would recommend. It is likely the simplest solution; additionally, it protects your printouts from interleaving with any other printouts going through Clojure's printing functions.

### The printing facilities' locking protocol

*Cautionary notice: the behaviour I describe below, as far as I can tell, is not mentioned anywhere in the JDK documentation, so any reliance on it is at your own risk (though it's likely not a terrible risk to take.)*

In this particular case it is worth noting that `*out*` already has a locking protocol in place which guarantees that individual bits of output from `print` & friends (such as the representations of their individual arguments, the spaces added between them and the newlines added in by `prn` / `println`) will not be interleaved.

The way this works is that `*out*` by default stores a `java.io.OutputStreamWriter` wrapping `java.lang.System.out`, also known as `System/out`. This `java.io.OutputStreamWriter` instance (in fact, any `java.io.Writer` instance) stores, in a protected `lock` field, an object it synchronizes on when performing writes. In the case of `*out*`, that object happens to be `System/out`. `print` and friends simply feed their arguments (and intervening spaces) to `*out*` one by one, so, as mentioned above, any individual argument is protected from being interleaved with other data in the output, but several arguments to single `print` call may be broken apart. Hence, building up a string and then printing it is thread-safe, while multi-argument `print` is convenient in simpler scenarios.

### Reasons for deadlock when locking `System/out` at the REPL

At this point I'd like to reiterate that I think avoiding a locking protocol using built-in objects to synchronize on (1) is a good idea in any case, (2) should hopefully solve your problem now and (3) is something I can recommend without asking for more details about your codebase. On to describing why such behaviour is to be expected at the REPL. *The discussion below applies to straight Clojure REPL, and not `lein repl` etc.*

First, the locks obtained by `synchronized` (Java) / `locking` (Clojure) are reentrant, which explains the fact that there are no problems with your `log` function in single-threaded use -- it's clear that once control has reached the body of the `locking` form, the current thread will be able to print `line` successfully (since it already holds the `System/out` monitor).

Introducing a deadlock involving `System/out` is simple enough:

```
(locking System/out
  @(future (println :foo))) ; note the @ !
```

With a function call in the middle, the system may or may not deadlock:

```
(defn f [fut]
  (locking System/out
    @fut))

;; will deadlock or not depending on whether the future is quick enough
(f (future (println :foo)))
```

Expanding upon the comment in the code snippet above, if the future fails to do all of its printing (which here involves `:foo`, a newline and probably a flush operation, though that last part depends on the current value of `*flush-on-newline*`) before `f` acquires the lock on `System/out`, it and `f`'s thread will deadlock. If the future is very fast to print, it'll be done before `f` acquires the lock and all will be fine.

Now, when working in the REPL, a similar condition is possible:

```
(defn f [i]
  (locking System/out
    (println :foo i)))

(dotimes [i 10]
  (future (f i)))
```

This deadlocks consistently on my machine without printing anything. With iteration count bumped to 10000, it instead tends to get in quite a lot of printouts, each on its own line, before deadlocking.

In contrast,

```
(defn f [i]
  (println :foo i))

(dotimes [i 10]
  (future (f i)))
```

prints out everything that it should, but "in no particular order"; in particular, the next prompt occurs in some arbitrary place, not typically near the end of the printed text.

Do note though that in every case if anything is printed at all, each individual item (`:foo`, the integers, the spaces, the newlines) is printed separately (that is without interleaving). This is, of course, due to the aforementioned locking performed by `*out*`.

Comment: Interesting, but I cannot get any of these to deadlock at my REPL. Machine/OS/environment dependent?

Comment: @A.Webb This may not (will not?) work in `lein repl`, but in a straight Clojure REPL `(locking System/out @(future (println :foo)))` should deadlock deterministically in OpenJDK 1.7, Clojure 1.5.1. If it doesn't for you, then `println` must not involve taking a lock on `System/out` in your environment. Of course all these scenarios may well be sensitive to various bits and pieces of the environment. In any case, I think hunting down the exact reason for the deadlock is less important than the general principle that one should be extremely circumspect about synchronizing on builtins.

Comment: @A.Webb Edited the answer to point out that the discussion about the REPL does not apply to `lein repl`. Client/server REPLs with `*out*` rebound to an object which has nothing to do with the JVM's own `System/out` will of course not take locks on `System/out` when calling standard printing functions.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk I was getting locking in repl in counterclockwise and lein run calling an embedded jetty.

Comment: @AnandPrakash Well, if you don't run into deadlock with `(locking System/out ...)` replaced by synchronizing on a sentinel you own, then clearly your problem is something to do with an existing locking protocol which also involves this lock. (In fact, a similar conclusion with a similar level of confidence could be drawn already from the system working with the `locking` form removed altogether.) As I tried to explain above, the discussion of one possible scenario where this happens (in the standard REPL) is mostly meant to give you an idea of how the deadlock *may* come about.

Comment: @AnandPrakash Tracing the proximate cause of the deadlock here with total confidence is not only pretty much impossible without looking at your codebase, but also pointless -- the crux of the matter is that you shouldn't synchronize on `System/out` in user code, or if you feel you absolutely need to, you should at least perform *lots* of due dilligence. I don't think the latter possibility is likely to be the case here though, since you can get interleaving-free logging printouts without synchronizing on builtins just fine, as demonstrated in the answer.

Comment: @AnandPrakash Also, uncovering just the most immediate cause of one particular deadlock scenario and calling it a day without removing the unnecessary synchronization on `System/out` would only give you a false sense of security, since another -- perhaps less frequently occurring -- scenario could still be hiding in the code (or be introduced by the fix for the first one!) and bite you later. To synchronize on an existing object in the system, you'd really need to see who takes locks on it and for what reason; a pretty overwhelming investigation to undertake.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk - finally got around to trying out your solutions. Locking on sentinel makes the problem go away. So your answer makes perfect sense. As far as I understand there is deadlock when two separate threads are locking on complementary locks in a pair waiting for the other. I understand that one is System/out. Which is the other member of the pair. I am going for the print solution. Thanks for the awesome response.

Answer (score -1):

From [locking](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/locking) documentation:

> Executes exprs in an implicit do, while holding the monitor of x.
>   Will release the monitor of x in all circumstances.

You are holding the monitor of System.out and when you got multiple parallel calls, you will get a deadlock exception.

*Although "Will release the monitor of x in all circumstances" isn't really clear to me.*

For experimenting, try to remove the call to (locking) function and see whether your system continues working or not.

Comment: Monitors are meant to be acquired from multiple threads at once; in absence of threads (the control abstraction -- parallel execution has nothing to do with this), there would be no point to having monitors in the system. What causes the problem is the fact that `System.out` is already involved in other locking protocols (as explained in my answer). "Will release the monitor of x in all circumstances" means that the lock will be released even if the body of the `locking` form fails to execute correctly (and, say, throws an exception). `try` / `finally`, basically.